# $_GET PHP form variable AJAX check 404 then submit form

Tags: php, ajax, http-status-code-404

I have a form on a page that accepts an 'ID', user inputs ID eg; 1026

The form submits to the same page ajax grabs the ID checks it against another site. I need to be able to let the form post if the response is NOT a 404 error and $_GET is true.

Heres what I have

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form#getid').submit(function(){
  var theid = $('input#id').val();
  var dataString = "id=" + theid;
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: dataString,
  success: function(response, status, xhr){
    if(status=="success") {
      $("#err-404").html(response);
    }
    else { alert(status+ ' - '+ xhr.status); }
  }
}
         }); 

  });

return false;
});
</script>
```

My form

```
<form id="getid" action="">
    <input type="text" name="id" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Go">
<div class="error" id="err-404"></div>
```

I think im on the right track, just not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you don't have to use a string for your data, don't.  You can use an array like so:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {'id': theid },
```

Which is cleaner and more maintainable.

As for your question, your code is a little unclear, but what you probably should do is `return false` at the end of the submit() event to prevent the form from submitting, and then in the AJAX event, if it's cleared for submission, do a `$('#getid').submit()`.  You may have to set some kind of flag (a hidden input or a data attribute) that you check on to avoid the AJAX-triggered submit from checking again, resulting in an infinite loop.

A note here: 404s should cause the `error()` callback in the AJAX handler to fire, so a 404 won't trigger the success callback you have set up.